# MD5 HASH ONLINE DELPHI

Tags: php, delphi, hash

Good day.
I'm using idhttp in my Delphi application.

I wonder if it is possible I Getting a MD5 hash of a file Online :

eg

> idhttp.get ( ' http.onedrive.com/arquive.rar ');

Is possible to return the MD5 of a file before downloading ... or just after I download could check the MD5 ?

For in php ... I use get_headers which returns some enteressantes data as Content- MD5 ... but almost any file owned this header ...

Ex php:

```
<?php $url = 'https://download3.vmware.com/software/player/file/VMware-player-6.0.4-2249910.exe';
echo '<pre>';
print_r(get_headers($url));

print_r(get_headers($url, 1));

?>



Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [Server] => Apache
    [ETag] => "df0743bf13519b6c461d50fac0fa0ded:1414635035"
    [Content-MD5] => 3wdDvxNRm2xGHVD6wPoN7Q==
    [Last-Modified] => Thu, 30 Oct 2014 02:10:35 GMT
    [Accept-Ranges] => bytes
    [Content-Length] => 98906456
    [Date] => Tue, 25 Nov 2014 19:11:28 GMT
    [Connection] => close
    [Content-Disposition] => attachment; filename="VMware-player-6.0.4-2249910.exe"
    [Content-Type] => application/x-octet-stream
)
```

I can use this ETag header to see if the file is identical? But how to catch it with DELPHI ??

> [ETag] => "df0743bf13519b6c461d50fac0fa0ded: 1414635035"

Comment: Are you looking for `TIdHTTP.Head`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962096/idhttp-just-get-response-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `TIdHTTP.Head()` to retrieve just the file's headers without having to downloade the file itself, or you can use `TIdHTTP.Get()` to download the file and get its headers at the same time.  Either method populates the `TIdHTTP.Response` sub-properties accordingly.

An [`ETag`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.19) header (which you can read from the `TIdHTTP.Response.ETag` property) allows you to detect if a file has been changed on the server.  When you download a file, you can save its `ETag` value as well, if one was provided.  You can then use that value later to check if the server-side file has been changed since the last time you downloaded it.

HTTP has a feature for that purpose called **Conditional GET**.  If you send a `GET` request with a [`If-None-Match`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.26) header (you can use the `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders` property for that) specifying the `ETag` you already have, the server can send you a [`304 Not Modified`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.5) response if the server-side `ETag` still matches that value, so you know your copy of the file is up-to-date and the server does not waste time and bandwidth trying to send the file again.

In your example. the file also has a [`Content-MD5`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.15) header.  That allows you to verify that the file you download was not modified/corrupted during the download process.  You can use the `TIdHTTP.Response.RawHeaders.Values['Content-MD5']` property to read that value, use the `TIdDecoderMIME` class to decode the value into bytes (it is base64 encoded), and use the `TIdHashMessageDigest5` class to calculate an MD5 hash of your local/downloaded file and compare it to the `Content-MD5` hash.

Comment: Very good explanation ... But I see is almost impossible to get Content-MD5, for most downloadable files do not have this header ... then return it empty = "" (empty) ... The only ways I see that maybe can work, but will never be 100%, is to use the Headers: ETag, Last-Modified and Content-Length ... Not 100%, but would help to get the files, since the Content-MD5 is always emptiness ...

How can I be about 200 files for download, the best way is the person downloading the file, and I check its MD5 and compare with one that I have stored in the database ...

Comment: Not all servers support `ETag`, either. Sometimes all you have to work with is `Last-Modified`.  Even `Content-Length` is not always used, if `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` or `Content-Type: multipart/...` is used (such as `multipart/byterange`). Use whatever headers are available, but worse case you may have to just rely on MD5 hashes of your local copy of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ETags are used for caching. This particular one uses MD5 and the timestamp, but on the PHP documentation you can also find etags such as `3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b`. The `df0743bf13519b6c461d50fac0fa0ded` string you see up front is the MD5 of the file, where the `1414635035` is the UNIX timestamp of the file's last modify date.

Enter the number at the end at a site such as [this website](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) and you'll see that the date that comes out is equal to the "Last-Modified" value.

Comment: Good explanation, I could understand what it is for this header ... in some cases:
 [5] => Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Feb 2011 23:40:45 GMT
 [6] => ETag: "cb32dac369cdcb1: 0"

Answer (score 1):

You can use Head request to get the information up front:

```
var
  ETag: string;

idhttp.head ('http.onedrive.com/arquive.rar');
ETag := idhttp.Response.ETag;
```